# Why does python show 'list index out of range' error?

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

I am very new to python, and started learning just 1 week ago. This program works very well except when I enter a number into guess1 variable that starts with 0.

```
import random
import sys
def script():
    while True:
        number1 = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        number1 = int(number1)
        while True:
            print ("Enter Your Guess")
            guess1 = input()
            guess1 = int(guess1)
            while True:
                if guess1 != number1:
                    break
                elif guess1 == number1:
                    print ("Your Guess Was Right!")
                    print ("Do you want to play again? Type YES or NO")
                    ask = input()
                    ask = str(ask)
                    if ask == "YES" or ask == "yes":
                        script()
                    elif ask == "NO" or ask == "no":
                        sys.exit()
                    else:
                        print ("Invalid input, try again.")
                        continue
            number = list(str(number1))
            guess = list(str(guess1))
            if len(guess) > 4:
                print ("Please type a 4-digit number")
                continue
            bulls = 0
            wr = 0
            cows = 0
            a = 3
            while a >= 0:
                if number[a] == guess[a]:
                    number[a] = 'a'
                    guess[a] = 'b'
                    bulls += 1
                a -= 1
            b = 0
            c = 0
            while b < 4:
                c = 0
                while c < 4:
                    if number[b] == guess[c]:
                        number[b] = 'a'
                        guess[c] = 'b'
                        wr += 1
                    c += 1
                b += 1
            z = bulls + wr
            cows = 4 - z
            bulls = str(bulls)
            cows = str(cows)
            wr = str(wr)
            print ("Cows: "+cows)
            print ("Bulls: "+bulls)
            print ("Wrongly Placed: "+wr)
        break
script()
```

This was a program written for a game, in which a 4-digit number is to be guessed. We do it by starting with a random number, and we get clues in the form of cows, bulls and wrongly placed. Cows mean the number is wrong, Bulls mean the number is right, and wrongly placed means the number is right but wrongly placed.
The whole thing works properly, but when I enter a number starting with 0, it shows something like this :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GuessingGame.py", line 61, in <module>
    script()
  File "GuessingGame.py", line 36, in script
    if number[a] == guess[a]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help, thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks to user @blue_note 's answer, The program works now! This is how it has been modified -

```
import random
import sys
def script():
    while True:
        number1 = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        number1 = int(number1)
        while True:
            print ("Enter Your Guess")
            guess1 = input()
            number = list(str(number1))
            guess = list(str(guess1))
            if guess[0] == 0:
                guess1 = str(guess1)
            else:
                guess1 = int(guess1)
            while True:
                if guess1 != number1:
                    break
                elif guess1 == number1:
                    print ("Your Guess Was Right!")
                    print ("Do you want to play again? Type YES or NO")
                    ask = input()
                    ask = str(ask)
                    if ask == "YES" or ask == "yes":
                        script()
                    elif ask == "NO" or ask == "no":
                        sys.exit()
                    else:
                        print ("Invalid input, try again.")
                        continue
            bulls = 0
            wr = 0
            cows = 0
            a = 3
            while a >= 0:
                if number[a] == guess[a]:
                    number[a] = 'a'
                    guess[a] = 'b'
                    bulls += 1
                a -= 1
            b = 0
            c = 0
            while b < 4:
                c = 0
                while c < 4:
                    if number[b] == guess[c]:
                        number[b] = 'a'
                        guess[c] = 'b'
                        wr += 1
                    c += 1
                b += 1
            z = bulls + wr
            cows = 4 - z
            bulls = str(bulls)
            cows = str(cows)
            wr = str(wr)
            print ("Cows: "+cows)
            print ("Bulls: "+bulls)
            print ("Wrongly Placed: "+wr)
        break
script()
```

Since my guess will always be wrong if the first digit is 0, I don't have the need to convert it into int.

Again, thanks for the help guys! This was my first question on the website. It is really a cool website.

Comment: Right before the line 36 where the error appears, do `print(len(number))`, `print(len(guess))` and `print(a)`. You should see that `a` is probably too large to index one of the two lists (note that length-1 is the largest possible index)

Comment: when you wrap as `int`, your leading zeroes are lost - so when you guess `'0010'`, wrapping this as an integer converts it to `10`.

Comment: For example,I Guess because if you use some number start with 0 but list(str(num)) will only have length of 3 or less. And later you called num[3], therefore out of index.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! It really helps. Converting to int was the mistake - so just removing that line will correct the mistake right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass, say, an integer starting with 0, say, `0123`, and you convert it to `int` in the next line, you are left with `123` (3 digits). Later, you do `number = list(str(number1))`, so your `number` is `['1', '2', '3']` (length 3). Then, you try to get `number[a]` with `a=3`, and that's were you get the error.

You could do something like

```
number = list(str(number1) if number1 > 999 else '0' + str(number1))
```